# Windows Service in Delphi with FireDAC MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, delphi, windows-services, firedac, delphi-12-athens

I am building a windows service using Delphi 12 (Athens) that listens port 80 and depending on the call it replies back with a message. To do so, I have setup the TService and OnStart it instantiates a TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.

In my main program, before the Application.CreateForm statement, I have declared:

`if WebRequestHandler <> nil then WebRequestHandler.WebModuleClass := WebModuleClass;`

where WebModuleClass: TComponentClass = TMyWebModule;
and TMyWebModule = class(TDataModule)

In the DataModule I use a TWebDispatcher and a TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink.

I have created a default action (mtGet) in the WebDispatcher. When I call the service with the default path ("/") I receive the correct responce

```
    Response.Content :=
    '<html>' +
    '<head><title>My Service</title></head>' +
    '<body>My Service Hello</body>' +
    '</html>';
```

So the service and the Http dispatcher work fine. The problem is that in another action (path /check_connection) I want to connect to MySQL v8.0 64bit

```
    if not dbMain.Connected then Begin
      try
        dbMain.Connected := True;
      except
        on e: EDatabaseError  do
        begin
          Response.Content := '{"code": 0,"message": "MySQL server connection error:'+E.Message+'"}';
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    End;
```

where dbMain: TFDConnection;

I am using a TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink in which I have defined in the VendorLib property the path "C:\MySQLConnectors\Win64\libmysql.dll"

The path, as well as, the version of the dll is correct (as I am using exactly the same code in a non-service Server Application which works fine).

But ... I am receiving the following message:

[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL]-314. Cannot load vendor library [C:\MySQLConnectors\Win64\libmysql.dll]. The specified module could not be found
Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has x64 bitness.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Is there any chance that a windows service cannot access local paths?

On another attempt, I copied the dll to the folder that my exe resides and set the VendorLib property at runtime:

```
    ExePath := TPath.GetDirectoryName(GetModuleName(HInstance));
    FDPhysMySQLDriverLink.VendorLib := TPath.Combine(ExePath, 'libmysql.dll');
```

But, again I receive the same message.